# Would a {sans-serif} tag be useful?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

When I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20750/changing-koma-script-font-family) question, my first impulse was to search for the countless other questions about sans-serif fonts. "sans-serif" yields 57 search results, yet there is no [sans-serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sans-serif) tag. Would such a tag be useful (at least for potential questioners)?

Note that there's a [texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texttt) tag that features 6 questions at the moment. And no, I don't want to flood the starting page by retroactively mass-retagging old questions. But maybe [sans-serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sans-serif) should be added to about a dozen questions with a high number of upvotes (or high-upvoted answers)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We've got 405 [fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts) questions until now. Regarding this and the number of your search results I think it would be useful to support font family tags such as [sans-serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sans-serif), [roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman) or [serifs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serifs) (synonym) and [typewriter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typewriter) for questions which are about such a font family.

[texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texttt) should be renamed to [typewriter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typewriter) to represent the topic (including the `\ttfamily` declaration and more) instead of just a command.

There's no hurry, we can introduce the tags and let it grow. Who knows, at some time we might have also tags regarding the shape and the weight... ok, we already see 21 [smallcaps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smallcaps), 16 [bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bold) and 4 [italic-correction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italic-correction) questions, so why not tags for the broader families.

Comment: BTW, we should possibly differentiate between {italic} (the font shape) and {italic-correction} (a very specific spacing problem in connection with {italic}).

Comment: Should it be {[tag:typewriter]} or {[tag:monospace]}?

Comment: @lockstep: I know :-) that specific tag just gives a hint that an italic related tag is already in use.

Comment: @Caramdir: I like [tag:monospaced] more, however [tag:typewriter] matches the LaTeX `\ttfamily`, `\texttt` better, typewriter typeface. In any case, one should be a synonym.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Stefan's answer and have accepted it. [roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman), [sans-serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sans-serif), [typewriter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typewriter), [bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bold), [italic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italic), and [smallcaps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smallcaps) seem useful tags to cover font families and font series/shapes.

A secondary effect of these (mostly) new tags seems to be that the scope of the [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) tag is diminished: It should still be used for general questions about formatting, but may be dispensed with for questions about font families/series/shapes. I propose the following tag wiki excerpt for [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting):

> [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) is for general
>   questions about formatting document
>   elements. Use this tag in addition to
>   other tags specifying what should be
>   formatted. For questions about font
>   families ([roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman),
>   [sans-serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sans-serif), [typewriter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typewriter)) or
>   font series/shapes (e.g. [bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bold),
>   [italic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italic), [smallcaps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smallcaps)), use the
>   appropriate tag instead.

Comment: Yes, [tag:formatting] shouldn't be used that much, if at all, so I think the wiki entry is ok. We could even add a tipp to think about if a better tag than the broad [tag:formatting], which doesn't really mean much, would be possible for the new question.

Comment: I view {formatting} as a catch-all tag for questions where no specific tag (or too many of them) would be appropriate. Its use should be discouraged somewhat, but not as much as the use of {latex-project}.

Comment: @Stefan: Please create the {typewriter} tag, make {texttt} and {monospaced} synonyms of it and merge existing questions.

Comment: done. A quick search for *monospaced* still shows some questions without a typewriter/monospaced tag.

Comment: @Stefan: I will retag them in the next days, and then start to look for questions to be tagged with {sans-serif}.